# Can dagger subcomponent builder set data (other than module)?

Tags: dagger-2

In reference to [Dagger 2 Subcomponent Documentation](https://dagger.dev/subcomponents), the example code shows that

```
@Singleton
class RequestRouter {
  @Inject RequestRouter(
      Provider<RequestComponent.Builder> requestComponentProvider) {}

  void dataReceived(Data data) {
    RequestComponent requestComponent =
        requestComponentProvider.get()
            .data(data)  // Data could be set here?
            .build();
    requestComponent.requestHandler()
        .writeResponse(200, "hello, world");
  }
}
```

From what I understood, that `Subcomponent.Builder` can only set the Module and Build, as per https://dagger.dev/api/2.10/dagger/Component.Builder.html

Just wonder how could we pass `Data` into the builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always make sure to read the [latest JavaDoc](https://dagger.dev/api/2.25.2/dagger/Component.Builder.html), `2.10` is *quite* old (Mar 20, 2017). I believe `@BindsInstance` was introduced with Dagger 2.12:

> - [...]
> - There may be setter methods annotated with `@BindsInstance`. These methods bind the instance passed to them within the component. See [`@BindsInstance`](https://dagger.dev/api/2.25.2/dagger/BindsInstance.html) for more information.
> - [...]

You can add various bindings to your component, e.g.

```
@BindsInstance
Builder foo(Foo foo); // allow binding of some `Foo`
```